# Собирать приложение с разным UI, не изменяя кода

Tags: c++, qt, консоль, cmake, gtk

Как организовать структуру приложения так, чтобы можно, не изменяя код, собирать и консольную, и GUI версии приложения?

Например, при параметре CMake `GUI=QT` собиралась бы Qt версия, а при `GUI=GTK` -- gtk, как это часто делается.

У меня есть несколько main.cpp для каждого случая, но по сути там происходит одно и то же (для gtk и Qt код дублируется, для консольной версии по-другому), поэтому думаю, что надо сделать некий класс View, одинаково создаваемый в одном main.cpp, а потом как-то на этапе компиляции выбрать версию. Как обычно такое делают?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь cmake, я бы не советовал делать отдельный класс где будет выбор того или иного способа от рисовки. С помощью cmake вы сможете определять какую  саб директорию добавить а внутри нее сможете с легкостью отрисовывать правильным способом. У нас принято делать именно так что бы не портить читаемость кода. Методы и функции работы того или иного алгоритма можно реализовать общие во имя избежания дублирования кода. Qt креатор отлично работает с cmake файлами и очень удобен в использовании.

Comment: Ту часть кода, которая должна быть разделяемой, и которую нужно не пересобирать, объедините под вызовом `add_library`.